# SSIS: ODBC Driver Manager The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssis, sqlite

I created a data flow task in SSIS. On double clicking, that task I added up ado.net source and destination. Under ado.net destination, I selected connection manager as odbc, and selected a user dsn.

Now, before doing all this stuff, I installed odbc driver from [ch-werner.de](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) and created a user dsn. In that process, I selected sqlite3 driver and my database is with the extension .sqlite.

Now, that dsn is available at ado.net destination. But when I select table it shows me this error that "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch".

[image]

To fix this stuff up, I researched some of the links. [One](http://www.sqlabs.com/blog/2012/02/odbc-driver-on-windows-64bit-clarification/) was like, creating a 32-Bit data source names by running c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. But, when I am trying to create a new dsn through that, it's not having SQLITE3 driver under create new datasource.

[image]

Comment: Actually both. First, I installed sqlodbc.exe and then sqlodbc-64.exe. In, both cases, the issue persists. Do you mind recommending me a link for 32 bit version?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment rather than editing! Perhaps the first thing to try might be to set "Run64BitRuntime" to "False" in the project properties (under "Debug", as described [here](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20run%20SSIS%20Packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm)); I don't know if that'll make a difference in this case, but it's certainly allowed stuff to run for me with drivers that only work in 32-bit mode. (Though I'd have thought that you'd be able to see the driver in odbcad32 if the 32-bit driver was correctly installed.)

Comment: Alright.....The error was at my end.......I reinstalled the 32 bit version of sqlodbc.exe......And, it worked fine

Comment: Great! It might help others in the future if you if you post the answer you've figured out to your own question and mark it as accepted. It wouldn't surprise me if someone else ran into the same error message in future and it's perfectly fine to answer your own question on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled sqlodbc. Restarted my pc and ran the sqlodbc installation again. Then, I was able to see sqlite3 drivers by running c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe